# Why I have problems when calling OCX C++ code using C#

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, ocx

I have a problem when calling an OCX method using C#. OCX component is developed in C++.

I get this error:

```
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020005): Los tipos
 no coinciden. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80020005
 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))\r\n   en
 System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
 BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
 msgData)\r\n   en
 MFCActiveXControl1Lib._DMFCActiveXControl1.LeoCadena(IntPtr
 nombreFichero, IntPtr contenidoFichero, Int32 LongitudFichero)\r\n  
 en AxMFCActiveXControl1Lib.AxMFCActiveXControl1.LeoCadena(IntPtr
 nombreFichero, IntPtr contenidoFichero, Int32 longitudFichero) en
 c:\\Temp\\PrinterManager\\Test\\MFCActiveXControl1\\Debug\\AxMFCActiveXControl1Lib.cs:línea
 43\r\n   en TestPrinterManager.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender,
 EventArgs e) en
 C:\\Temp\\PrinterManager\\Test\\TestPrinterManager\\TestPrinterManager\\Form1.cs:línea
 77"
```

C++ signatures are:

```
*void flushFiles();
LONG LeoCadena(unsigned char * nombreFichero,
             unsigned char * contenidoFichero,
             int LongitudFichero);*
```

I have modified the generated visual studio wrapper so that the exported methods are:

IL file:

```
*void  flushFiles()
int32  LeoCadena(native int nombreFichero, 
             native int contenidoFichero,
             int32 LongitudFichero)*
```

cs file:

```
*public virtual void flushFiles()
public virtual int LeoCadena(System.IntPtr nombreFichero, System.IntPtr contenidoFichero, int 
                             longitudFichero)*
```

When I call the method using C#, I used this code:

```
*string file_xml = @"C:\proyectos\fichero.xml";
string texto_xml;
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_xml);
texto_xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(texto_xml);
int longitud = arr.Length; 
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)) * arr.Length);
Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, longitud);
axMFCActiveXControl1.LeoCadena(ptr, ptr, longitud);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);*
```

Do you know why I get this error?

I use 32 bits platform and .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: The (untranslated) error says that the types are wrong, which they are. You aren't calling C++ code, you're calling *COM* code. A COM string is *not* a `char *`. In fact, using C-style strings in C++ is a **very** bad idea. In COM, strings are Unicode (UTF16). There are far too many problems in this code. It looks like no COM-related guideline or C++ library was used at all. Even using an OCX is weird- that's a UI component. Why call a UI component from background code?

Comment: When you have a proper COM library, whether OCX or DLL, you *don't* import the functions as if they were C functions. You [add the type library as a COM reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/fwawt96c(v=vs.100)) and use the types and methods almost the same way you would a .NET library.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If all you want is to call a C function from .NET, COM is overkill. Creating a COM component is very complex and too hard to do without using a library like [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/atl-com-desktop-components?view=msvc-160).

Comment: What do you mean by "IL" file? Do you mean IDL? You can't change an IDL but keep the C/C++ signature as is. PS: @PanagiotisKanavos - you can perfectly use C-style parameters char* with COM. You're probably confusing COM with COM "Automation" (IDispatch, VARIANT, BSTR, TLB, etc. which can actually limit data types but it's only a superset of COM, which may be at use here indeed).

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, IDL - stuck keyboard. As for c-style strings, yes, I remember something like that 21 years ago. Which was a *terrible* idea back then but far, far worse nowadays, unless you were in the Windows-95 line. Then it was simply awful, leading to a ton of codepage conversion issues. With Windows NT a Unicode OS, using `char *` is asking for serious trouble.

Comment: @SimonMourier imagine using C-style string in the Netherlands. Or Germany, now that they do so much business with Russia. Or *every single country* that does business with China. The late 1990s were fun

Comment: Do you _really need_ that OCX? ;)

Comment: I don't need this particular OCX. This is only a test, so that I can reproduce the behaviour of an OCX that I need to use, but I don't have its source code, and I can not understand why it is throwing the same exception. The real app can't use ActiveX, so I need to encapsulate it in a .NET DLL.